# What does 会えなくなっちゃって mean and why?

Tags: grammar

I'm very sorry, I just couldn't figure it out. If you could state what grammar pieces the term uses and how they affect the word, that would be great.

So far I know that the 会えなくて is the te form of negative '出来る' form.

Sorry!

Answer (score 7):

Sure, it's a pretty simple construction, but it's in informal language so it might be a little tricky.

In its fullest form it would be 会えなくなってしまって, with 会える + ない + なる + てしまう + て, with each of the components inflected accordingly.

会えない is the negative potential, i.e. "cannot meet"

会えなくなる, with the added なる, means that "it became such that (someone) couldn't meet"

てしまう is a construction that means something sort of unexpected or undesirable or unintentional happens, so the flavor here is that someone became unable to meet through some unfortunate circumstance.

The final て is just there to connect it to the rest of the sentence.

Comment: All great for parsing the grammar, but the asker also wanted  to know what it means which is roughly "in the end, I was not able to meet him." but then with て as the ending, it will need to be altered to conjoin to whatever follows in the sentence.